# Pagination on DjangO - No Values

Tags: python, django-3.0, paginator

I am following a specific guide and basically hit a roadblock I cannot debug.

I implemented Paginator into my blog site and was hoping to show the current page / end of page.
But for some reason the page values are blank.
What would you think is the reason behind this issue? Do you think that this has something to do with my VS compiler not importing paginator properly?

[list HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ7SW.png)

pagination block code

```
<div class="pagination">
<span class="step-links">
    {% if page.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
        Page {{ page.number }} of {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}.
    </span>
    {% if page.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
    {% endif %}
</span>
</div>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.
def post_list(request):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3) # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request,
                 'blog/post/list.html',
                 {'page': page,
                  'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                                   status='published',
                                   publish__year=year,
                                   publish__month=month,
                                   publish__day=day)
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/detail.html',
                  {'post': post})
```

List HTML Code

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %} My Blog {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>My Blog</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h2>
            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
                {{ post.title }}
            </a>
        </h2>

        <p class="date">
            Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
        </p>
        {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% include "pagination.html" with page=post %}
    
{% endblock %}
```

[Github Link](https://github.com/dwtang612/My-Blog-Application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `page=posts` rather than `page=post`.

```py
{% include "pagination.html" with page=posts %}
```

Comment: Don't, it happens to all of us :)